# Binding to Window.DataContext.ViewModelCommand inside a ItemsControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I Have some window like:

```
<Window>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemList}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Command="{Binding ViewModelCommand}">My Button</Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

This window has the `DataContext` property defined with an instance of:

```
public class MyVM
{
    public IEnumerable<FooType> MyItemList { get; set; }
    public ICommand ViewModelCommand { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that the `Button.Command` binding is not working. I'm guessing that the problem is because my button is inside ItemsControl, so the binding is looking for `ViewModelCommand` inside of the object of `FooType`.

So how can I make this bind properly?

Comment: Pretty sure you guessed right. The DataContext inside that DataTemplate will be the `FooType` item. Try `{Binding DataContext.ViewModelCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}`

Comment: Option #2 is give FooType a ViewModelCommand property with a get/set and have the owning VM hand off its own ViewModelCommand to each of them. But that sucks.

Comment: Hey this worked!, can you put in a answer to I check as correct? Also, why AncestorType=ItemsControl? Can you explain why?

Comment: Done. Let me know if my explanation didn't make much sense, it's late and, you know, libations and all that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DataContext` inside that `DataTemplate` will be the `FooType` item; that's what the `ItemTemplate` is there for: To display each item.