# In WPF MVVM, i have a usercontrol with a check box, how do i connect a command to the viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am still new to WPF and MVVM and am trying to keep the seperation between View and View Model.
i have an app, essentially a projects task list app, in this i create projects and within each project i can create a set of tasks. Most is working well, but essentially i cannot get a command binding on a checkbox in a user control to work using DP, inherited datacontext etc. i always ge a binding failed error when running the app. i am trying to bing to a command in the viewmodel of the view which contains the user controls.

i created a user control to pull the task data together in the view, the command is on the checkbox

```
    <UserControl x:Class="TaskProjectApp.Controls.TaskControl"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TaskProjectApp.Controls"
                 mc:Ignorable="d" 
                 d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="300">
        <Grid Background="LightBlue">
            <StackPanel Margin="5,5,5,5">
                <TextBlock x:Name="titleTB"
                           Text="title" 
                           FontSize="20" 
                           FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="DescriptionTB"
                            Text="description.."
                            FontSize="15" 
                            Foreground="DodgerBlue"/>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="priority"
                           Text="0" 
                           FontSize="15" 
                           FontStyle="Italic"/>
                    <CheckBox Grid.Column="1"
                              x:Name="iscomplete"
                              Command="{Binding SetComplete}"/>
                </Grid>
                
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

in the user control code behind i have set the DP and the set text function is working

```
namespace TaskProjectApp.Controls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for TaskControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class TaskControl : UserControl
    {
        public UserTask Task
        {
            get { return (UserTask)GetValue(TaskProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TaskProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Task.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TaskProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Task", typeof(UserTask), typeof(TaskControl), new PropertyMetadata(new UserTask()
            {
                Title = "title",
                Description = "none",
                Comments = "none"
            }, SetText));



        private static void SetText(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TaskControl task = d as TaskControl;
            if (task != null)
            {
                task.titleTB.Text = (e.NewValue as UserTask).Title;
                task.DescriptionTB.Text = (e.NewValue as UserTask).Description;
                task.priority.Text = (e.NewValue as UserTask).Priority.ToString();
                task.iscomplete.IsChecked = (e.NewValue as UserTask).IsComplete;
            }
        }
        public TaskControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

now to make this work i set the binding of the user control in the window as so, the listview takes the usercontrols and implements the observable collection of tasks.

```
<Window x:Class="TaskProjectApp.Views.ProjectsView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TaskProjectApp.Views"
        xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:TaskProjectApp.Controls" 
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ProjectsView" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <uc:ProjectControl Project="{Binding UserProject}" />
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock Text="Task List"/>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTask}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <uc:TaskControl Task="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            <Button Content="Add Task"
                    Command="{Binding NewProjectTask}"/>
            <Button Content="Delete Task"
                    Command="{Binding DeleteProjectTask}"/>

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

this seems to completely stop me using the command, i set the datacontext in the code behind, to the whole window

```
 public partial class ProjectsView : Window
    {
        public ProjectViewModel ProjectViewModel { get; set; }

        public ProjectsView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public ProjectsView(UserProject userProject)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ProjectViewModel = new ProjectViewModel(userProject);
            DataContext = ProjectViewModel;
        }
    }
```

and reading trying to solve this has shown that the usercontrol should inherit the datacontext of the parent window.

i have seen solutions using relative paths and DPs for the commands as well as people saying these are not needed just let the inherited datacontext handle it.

but i have tried all three an neither works.

the interface shows me a message box saying no datacontext found, although i notice this is the case when you set the datacontext in code behind and not the xaml.

the SetCommand is created  in the projects view model and its a property not a field as i have seen this fail for that reason too.

```
namespace TaskProjectApp.ViewModels
{
    public class ProjectViewModel
    {
        public UserProject UserProject { get; set; }

        public ProjectViewModel(UserProject userProject)
        {
            UserProject = userProject;
            Tasks = new ObservableCollection<UserTask>();
            NewProjectTask = new NewProjectTaskCommand(this);
            DeleteProjectTask = new DeleteProjectTaskCommand(this);
            SetComplete = new SetCompleteCommand();
            ReadTaskDatabase();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<UserTask> Tasks { get; set; }

        public NewProjectTaskCommand NewProjectTask { get; set; }

        public DeleteProjectTaskCommand DeleteProjectTask { get; set; }

        public SetCompleteCommand SetComplete { get; set; }

        public UserTask SelectedTask { get; set; }

        public void ReadTaskDatabase()
        {
            List<UserTask> list = new List<UserTask>();
            using (SQLiteConnection newConnection = new SQLiteConnection(App.databasePath))
            {
                newConnection.CreateTable<UserTask>();
                list = newConnection.Table<UserTask>().ToList().OrderBy(c => c.Title).ToList();
            }
            Tasks.Clear();
            foreach (UserTask ut in list)
            {
                if (ut.ProjectId == UserProject.Id)
                {
                    Tasks.Add(ut);
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if anyone can point out where i am going wrong tat will be great as i fear i am now not seeing the wood for the trees.

Comment: `<uc:TaskControl Task="{Binding}"/>` is inside ListView.ItemTemplate, which means its DataContext will be UserTask object. `{Binding SetComplete}` inside TaskControl  fails because SetComplete is not a property of UserTask class

Comment: usuall one has to declare dependency properties in their UserControl to connect internal visual elemets to external data source

Comment: Hi Ash, thanks for that, that would make sense, but even if i created a DP for the command, if i have set the datacontext to a UserTask with the binding you highlight, how could i connect to the SetCompleteCommand which is in the viewmodel datacontext

Comment: i tried the DP option using this tutorial https://www.pmichaels.net/2014/10/12/creating-and-binding-to-a-custom-user-control-in-mvvm-cross/ but still get the same binding issue, so as you say the issue is the context is now the Task not the viewmodel, so how can you set the DP to update on the task but also the command to fire?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37040712/binding-to-window-datacontext-viewmodelcommand-inside-a-itemscontrol

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution thanks to Ash link [Binding to Window.DataContext.ViewModelCommand inside a ItemsControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37040712/binding-to-window-datacontext-viewmodelcommand-inside-a-itemscontrol) not sure how i missed it, maybe wrong key words. anyway because the datacontext of the usercontrol is being made into my data class in the observable list Tasks

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock Text="Task List"/>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTask}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <uc:TaskControl Task="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            <Button Content="Add Task"
                    Command="{Binding NewProjectTask}"/>
            <Button Content="Delete Task"
                    Command="{Binding DeleteProjectTask}"/>

        </StackPanel>
```

you need to use a relative path inside the user control to look up past the ItemTemplate to the ListView itself as this uses the viewmodel data context to bind to, so has access to the right level

```
<UserControl x:Class="TaskProjectApp.Controls.TaskControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TaskProjectApp.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid Background="LightBlue">
        <StackPanel Margin="5,5,5,5">
            <TextBlock x:Name="titleTB"
                       Text="title" 
                       FontSize="20" 
                       FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="DescriptionTB"
                        Text="description.."
                        FontSize="15" 
                        Foreground="DodgerBlue"/>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock x:Name="priority"
                       Text="0" 
                       FontSize="15" 
                       FontStyle="Italic"/>
                <CheckBox Grid.Column="1"
                          x:Name="iscomplete"
                          Command="{Binding DataContext.SetComplete, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"/>
            </Grid>
            
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

this might be limiting in future as it measn the usercontrol will look for a listview to bind the command, but it solves the immediate issue.